# "она мног(иx/о) кого не одобряет"

Tags: грамматика

Which one is correct?

> Церковь мно**гиx** кого не одобряет

or

> Церковь мно**го** кого не одобряет

Comment: The second one is correct. And more knowledgeable people than me will provide an answer explaining why :).

Comment: "Многих не одобряет" or "Много кого не одобряет".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I think that only the second variant ("много кого") is correct.**

There are two different parts of speech in the examples you gave.

In the first example, *многих* is a form of *многие*, which is an adjective and modifies *кого*. It has the same structure as *многие люди*, or if you put it in the same context:

> Церковь не одобряет многих людей.

If you are a native speaker, you can feel for yourself that *многие кто* sounds incorrect. I didn't manage to find any literature that describes syntactic properties of *кто*, but I think that it can hardly be modified by any adjectives at all. The only examples of this kind I can come up with are colloquial back-check questions like:

> — Многие монофизиты пострадали в то время.
>   — Многие кто?

In the second example, *много* is an adverb. I didn't find anything about this function of *много* in a dictionary, but it seems to be very similar in function to *мало* in the following examples:

> Он мало с кем разговаривает.
>   Мало кто об этом помнит. 
>   Он мало где бывает.

And there is a special entry for this kind of usages of *мало* in the dictionary:

> *мало* (с местоим. и нареч.).
>   Указывает на недостаточность, незначительное количество, редкость того, что обозначает местоименное слово. 
>   *М. что хорошего я услышал (немного).*
>   *М. где он бывает (в немногих местах).*
>   *М. какой прохожий остановится у калитки (немногие)*.
>  
>   *М. когда солнце светит с утра (изредка).*

It can be translated as:

> *мало* (with pronouns and adverbs).
>   Denotes insufficient, insignificant amount or rarity of the thing that is referred to by the pronoun.

Therefore, we can assume that *много кто* is a correct form, too.

Comment: I think the easier explanation is that word in correct case tends to "rhyme", "click" with the question for the same case. Therefore, "много кого". It clicks like a magnet lock!

Comment: @alamar - honestly, neither "много кого" nor "многиx кого" strikes me as "clicking right".

Answer (score 0):

I think both variants are colloquial.

The correct form would be:

> Церковь многих не одобряет.

*Translation: The Church disapproves of many [people].*

or

> Церковь много чего не одобряет.

*Translation: The Church disapproves of many [things].*

though in the second case,

> Церковь многое не одобряет.

would also be a better grammar.

Comment: Why would it be a “better” grammar? Sure, it may well be more refined, official, literary, publishable version, but why exactly the colloquial variant be “worse”?